# How is this possible ?? can someone explain this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

iam making easy battleship game. but there is something that doesnt make sense for me. when there is strictly append in the first loop it has different output than if i wrote the same thing with variable..

```
import random

BOARD = []

for i in range(5):
    BOARD.append(["O"]*5)

x = random.randint(1,5)
y = random.randint(1,5)

while True:
    for i in BOARD:
        print(" ".join(i))

    row = int(input(": "))
    column = int(input(": "))

    if x == row and y == column:
        print("you win")
    else:
        BOARD[x - 1][y - 1] = "X"
```

in case of miss there is output like this

```
O O O O O
O X O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
```

but if i wrote this code.. which is similar to previous.. only difference is a variable in the first loop... it has totaly different output..

```
import random

BOARD = []

Q = ["O"]*5

for i in range(5):
    BOARD.append(Q)

x = random.randint(1,5)
y = random.randint(1,5)

while True:
    for i in BOARD:
        print(" ".join(i))

    row = int(input(": "))
    column = int(input(": "))

    if x == row and y == column:
        print("you win")
    else:
        BOARD[x - 1][y - 1] = "X"
```

but there is output like this.. it doesnt make sense for me

```
O x O O O
O X O O O
O x O O O
O x O O O
O x O O O
```

is there on this site anyone who can explain this ??? nobody can help

Comment: Here `BOARD` contains a list with **references to the same list**. So if you modify `BOARD[0]` then the update is reflected in `BOARD[1]`...

Comment: You are marking the `X` based on `x` and `y` which are randomly chosen...

Comment: Please give some useful information in the title, or we have to vote down this question.

Answer (score 1):

This must solve the issue:

```
import random

BOARD = []

Q = ["O"]*5

for i in range(5):
    BOARD.append(list(Q))

x = random.randint(1,5)
y = random.randint(1,5)

while True:
    for i in BOARD:
        print(" ".join(i))

    row = int(input(": "))
    column = int(input(": "))

    if x == row and y == column:
        print("you win")
    else:
        BOARD[x - 1][y - 1] = "X"
```

You must make copy of the list Q: BOARD.append(list(Q))